# Bing Maps: Adding a PushPin for every turn after calculateDirections is called

Tags: bing-maps

I'm working on a "snap to road" piece of functionality for Bing Maps. My thoughts were that once a user clicked on the map, the DirectionsManager class would calculate the route, so that if a user wanted to make a route that rounded a curve, they wouldn't have to click several times. They could just click twice, and the page would do the rest. (BTW, if anyone has a better way of doing this, please let me know - this is my first pass at a solution.)

I was experimenting with the DirectionsManager examples on MSDN, and cutting down the example code regaring the RouteLeg class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312823), I have this basic code:

```
function directionsModuleLoaded() {
    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

    var startWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(42.71926499622451,-84.57241695374249) });
    var endWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(42.71390477940529,-84.5766870304942) });

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(startWaypoint);
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(endWaypoint);

    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
}

function displayMessage(e) {
    alert("The calculated route has " + e.route[0].routeLegs[0].itineraryItems.length + " direction steps.");
}
```

This does work. I enter a pair of Lat/Long values, and it calculates and displays the "rounded" route. What I was hoping for was a way to place a PushPin on each part of the route where there was a change of direction, so if it took three small routes to turn a corner, there would be PushPins displayed, one at each point where the two segments met. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [getAllWaypoints()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx) from the DirectionManager class to get an array of all waypoints.

Foreach waypoint, you can call [getLocations()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312838.aspx) to get the location of the waypoint object.

Then you can create a pushpin at each location, by passing waypoint.getLocations() to the pushpin [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615.aspx) as well as any other set options, then adding the pushpin to the map.